# Z-Index in combination with position: fixed and transitions (CSS)

Tags: css, position, z-index, transition

I'm setting up a new portfolio website and use the [Onepage Scroll Plugin by Pete R.](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

I added a fix navigation bar and now want to have elements inside a slide overlapping this navigation. Here's a code example at codepen:

http://codepen.io/terrorpixel/pen/BNxYxq

HTML

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
  <div>Bring me to the front!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    height: 82px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;  
    background:rgba(0,255,0,.85);
}

.container {
    background:blue;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 2ms ease 0s;
    transition: all 2ms ease 0s;
    height: 5000px; 
    z-index:1;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container div {
    padding: 250px 100px;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    right:0; 
    top:0;
    background:red;
}
```

I try to get the red box to the front. I think the failure belongs to the fact that I'm using z-index in different stacking contexts. The  inside the .container hadn't worked, too.. Is there actually a possibility to realize that :/?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `.container div` outside of `.container`.
When you place a positioned element inside a positioned element, the children start a new stacking order but it starts in context with the parents value. So even if you specify a z-index value of 10000 to a child of a parent with a z-index of 2 its like the child has a z-index of 2.10000.

This example is crude but you get the idea:

```css
nav {
  height: 82px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: background 1.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .85);
}
.container {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1%, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2ms ease 0s;
  transition: all 2ms ease 0s;
  height: 5000px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.front {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%; /* half of 30% (the left over of 70% container width) */
  top: 82px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="front">Bring me to the front!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your detailed answer and code example! Now I understand the problem much more better. I'll try to change the structure like you did and hope it will work :)